# IRF630N MOSFET burns after a couple of times in use

Tags: arduino, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, low-side

I made a simple circuit using an IRF630N to drive my loud buzzer. The Arduino code is very simple, just high and low on the pin for a fraction of time. Following is the schematic of the circuit

After using it a couple of times, I found my MOSFET dead when I turned my board on again and ran the Arduino code. During the operation the MOSFET was cool and there was no sign of heat after the operation. I checked the datasheet and it says Vgs +-20.

How can the MOSFET be broken without any sign of heat?

Would it damage the MOSFET if Vgs exceeds  24V?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Inductance of "long" wires ... R40 seems too high ... (10 to 50 Ohm max).

Comment: I think the gate resistor must be higher. I can see that R40 is 1K. I did a similar project using IRF540N. I used a 10K resistor in series with the base.

Comment: Show us a more clear picture of your physical setup. Does the green and white wire go to your Arduino?  What's going on with the brown wires?  They don't look like what you have drawn on the schematic. My guess is you have hooked up the gate and pull-down resistors as a voltage divider and the MOSFET is not turning all the way on.

Comment: @vir I put another speaker beside the circuit, to show how this speaker looks like

Comment: @liaifat85 This is a MOSFET, not a BJT. It has no base, it has a gate. And 1kΩ is high for a gate resistor, nevermind 10kΩ.

Comment: What's wrong with 1k? A ~5us rise/fall time is fine for switching at audio frequencies, and likely alleviates a lot of concerns with flyback.

Comment: Small nitpick: Your schematic does not match the picture, R41 does not go to the Arduino pin, it goes to the gate of Q1. There R40 and R41 form a voltage divider which puts 91% of the pin voltage on the gate - on a 5V Arduino that means that the gate gets about 4.5V

Comment: If the gate touches 24V inadvertently or by purpose, the gate will be damaged. Even if touches before the 1K resistor. Judging from the picture, there is a high risk that the 24V wire had touched the gate for a short time.

Comment: You had me going with the upside down schematic for a while there.

Comment: I made a mistake guys the problem was not MOSFET, maybe it is a ground effect, but I couldn't fix it yet, please leave your comments

Comment: @Hamidsk I've rolled your question back to how it was when you received two answers. If you have a new situation please don't edit your original question but ask a new question then, you'll get the benefit of opening up your new situation to everyone. Editing your question above just makes the casual reader downvote the answers below based on them not appearing to address your modified question.

Comment: @Hamidsk - Hi, There's a problem here: You have now explained that the issue is not as you originally described, so this is not a true question - yet people have answered in good faith, based on what was described. (This also makes it too late to change the question, so it was correctly rolled-back to its original version.) || I don't plan on deleting the question (and therefore its answers), but we don't want new people to spend time answering a question whose details are wrong. Therefore I'm closing the question, to prevent new answers.

Comment: (Summary: This question is now closed since vital details in the question are wrong. However answers have already been given, in good faith, based on those incorrect details. Therefore it is too late to make major changes to the question, to correct it. The OP has now asked a [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706601/mosfet-does-not-work-if-usb-is-disconnected-to-a-microcontroller) with different details.)

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention what type of Arduino it is, but the most likely cases are 3.3 or 5.0V output, which are not nearly enough to activate the IRF630.

Consider at least an IRL630, 
https://www.vishay.com/docs/91303/irl630.pdf 
which is rated for 4V turn-on, and probably still draws fair current at 3.3V even if it's not guaranteed at that voltage.  There are zillions of other types available, rated for the required voltage and current (apparently around 24V 2A, but if this range is wider due to supply or load range, you will have to determine what is suitable based on that); check with your supplier; select from "logic level" types.

I'm not concerned about the gate resistor value, as you're probably switching at audio frequencies.  If this is not the case, do consider reducing the gate resistor, or limiting switching frequency to a couple of kHz.

Some snubbing on the drain will probably be welcome.  This can be as simple as a series resistor and capacitor connected across the FET, D-S, or a TVS from S to D, or other RCD rate or clamp type snubbers.  Typical values would be R comparable to load resistance (say, 10Ω non-inductive), and C a few nF.

Answer (score 2):

> *how can Mosfet broken without any sign of heat?*

It could be: -

- inductive load back-emf over-volting the MOSFET when it deactivates (speakers have inductance and so does wiring)
- under-driven gate causing thermal runaway (normally barely noticeable to the feel) but particularly a problem on an IRF630 driven from a 5 volt IO pin when the drain current is 100 mA or above
- badly connected grounds
- bad handling of the MOSFET causing severe ESD degradation
- a fake part

> *if Vgs exceed the limits, may it wear and tear the Mosfet 24v?*

It could totally destroy the device or, it could push it to the point where failure was imminent.

Comment: what do you mean by "under-driven gate"?do you suggest using diode protection?

Comment: Where the gate source voltage is not enough to activate the MOSFET properly into full conduction, you can get near instant thermal runaway without any suggestions of the device getting warm.

Comment: @Hamidsk please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @Hamidsk Andy means that the voltage you used to drive the gate may have been too low. If you look in the datasheet, in particular Rdson in the Electrical Characteristics, you can see the on-state resistance is only specified for Vgs=10V, but you're driving it with (I assume) 5V. If you look at the graphs further down, you do see characteristics at lower gate voltages, but those are 1) typical, not worst case, and 2) pretty marginal. Your mosfet is not a great choice at 5V gate drive. However, for what it's worth, I suspect back-emf and/or ESD are more likely culprits.

Comment: On top of that R41 (if connected to the gate as on the picture) and R40 form a voltage divider worsening the situation. Even if R41 is connected to ground as on the schematic, it could lower the voltage.. Perhaps a combination of several causes.